# How to reduce the height of the textbox

Tags: jquery-mobile

Hi How to reduce the height of the textbox...

```
HTML CODE:
<textarea id="" name="" placeholder=""></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#pageID div textarea.ui-input-text {height: 20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `rows` attribute you can change the number of lines in your textarea, not exactly the height property (that is specified in pixels), but I think `rows` is what you want. Example with 20 lines of height:

```
<textarea id="" rows="20" name="" placeholder=""></textarea>
```

In the same manner there's a `cols` attribute to specify the width of the textarea in characters.

Answer (score 0):

For textarea use `rows` "or and" `cols` and set the value that you want,
for normal textbox you can set a style for it as `style="height:20px;"`

Answer (score 0):

By using CSS you can adjust the height of `<textarea>`

First, put some name on your `id`

```
<textarea id="box" name="" placeholder=""></textarea>
```

Then, your desired height in `px`

```
#box {
    height:10px; /* example */
}​
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bt24N/).